# SystemVerilog constructor return value

Tags: constructor, system-verilog

I want to do something like this, but it results in an error:

```
class MyPacket;
  function MyPacket not_fun_ction();
    $display("not fun");
    return this;
  endfunction
endclass

module testbench;
  MyPacket temp;
  initial
  begin
    temp = MyPacket::new().not_fun_ction().not_fun_ction();
  end
endmodule
```

I know, that I can't specify a return value to the constructor ([link](https://www.project-veripage.com/sv_class_5.php)).
But the constructor returns the object reference, because this assignment works: `temp = MyPacket::new();`. Why can't I just call a member method on the returned reference? In most other object oriented programming languages, this should be valid.

(I know, that it works when I write it as 2 separate statements:

```
temp = MyPacket::new(); 
temp.not_fun_ction().not_fun_ction();`,
```

but I wanted to write it in a single statement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two syntactical problems with what you are trying to do.

1. function chaining was just officially added to the IEEE 1800-2023 LRM, although most tools already support it
2. Because of `new` being a reserved keyword, it can only appear as the sole RHS of an assignment; not as part of a larger expression. (in this case, a function chain)

There is an easy workaround to get what you are looking for by creating a static wrapper for the constructor.

```
    class MyPacket;
      function MyPacket not_fun_ction();
        $display("not fun");
        return this;
      endfunction
      static function MyPacket New;
        New = new;
      endfunction
    endclass
    
    module testbench;
      MyPacket temp,t;
      initial
      begin
        temp = MyPacket::New().not_fun_ction().not_fun_ction();
      end
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

*But the constructor returns the object reference* -- wrong. It works in c++ but not in verilog.

> LRM: The new operation is defined as a function with no return type, and like any other function, it shall be
> nonblocking. Even though new does not specify a return type, the left-hand side of the assignment
> determines the return type.

So, it is a special type of a function which only works in direct assignments only. The following will work:

```
initial
  begin
    temp = new;
    temp.not_fun_ction().not_fun_ction();
  end
```